# Excel: how to generate the list of IDs after I select the items from a list?

Tags: forms, excel, selection, generator

I am thinking to generate a list of IDs after I select the items from a data sheet. But I don't know where to start. Can you give me some hints? Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Here is how my worksheet looks like. I have five columns, namely, ID, Category, Name, Sub Name, and Checkbox. Checkbox is now empty, because I don't know how to make one. But ideally, I want to create a check box for each item (each row), so I can choose the items I want. At the bottom of the worksheet, I want to create a button, called "Click to generate the selected list witht their IDs". Ideally, I can click it to get a list of IDs of the selected (checked) items from above.

Furthermore, I am thinking to create a fold-in Category and Name, so smaller items, such as Pink Lady and Royal Crisp can be folded as Apple. When I select Apple, automatically, I select both Pink Lady and Royal Crisp.

Are these requirements doable? Please help! Thanks in advance!

```
ID  Category    Name    Sub Name    Checkbox
1   Fruit   Apple   Pink Lady   
2   Fruit   Apple   Royal Crisp 
3   Fruit   Banana  Brazil  
4   Fruit   Banana  Agentine    
5   Fruit   Grape       
6   Fruit   Orange      
7   Fruit   Peach       
8   Vegetable   Celery      
9   Vegetable   Carrot  Baby Carrot 
10  Vegetable   Carrot  Ordinary Carrot 
11  Vegetable   Cabbage     
12  Vegetable   Potato  Idaho Potato    
13  Vegetable   Potato  White Potato    
14  Vegetable   Tomato  Cherry Tomato   
15  Vegetable   Tomato  Ordinary Tomato 

Click to generate the selected list witht their IDs
```

Comment: @pnuts thanks, that would work, if the data set is small. Actually, I have quite a long table, say 10K rows or so, and I am really looking forward to the fold in selection (so I can select multiple items by group). Does it make sense?

Comment: @pnuts thanks anyway. Because there are multiple rows. If one decides to choose all the items in one group (items within same Name, or same Category) and to be efficient, one doesn't want to click 100 times compared to 1 click, if the 100 items (sub name) can be folded into just one group (Name), or even better one category (Category).

Comment: Filter can select the group of items, but won't automatically put a check sign after each of them, right? Or am I missing anything you've mentioned?